# Interface to base class method

Tags: c++

For code below, are there any other ways to access a method in base through interface?

```
struct Base {
    void funct_base() {
        printf("Common function for class Foo and class Bar\n");
    }
};

struct IFoo {
    virtual ~IFoo() {}
    virtual void funct_a() = 0;
    // would like to access Base::bunct_base() from here
};

struct Foo : public Base, public IFoo {
    virtual void funct_a() {
        printf("I am Foo:: funct A\n");
    }
};

class IBar {
    virtual ~IBar() {}
    virtual void funct_a() = 0;
    // would like to access Base::bunct_base() from here
};

class Bar : public Base, public IBar {
    virtual void funct_a() {
        printf("I am Bar:: funct A\n");
    }
};
```

I know this can be done, but I just do not like the wrapper, it does not seem clean:

```
struct IBar {
    virtual ~IBar() {}
    virtual void funct_a() = 0;
    virtual void funct_base() = 0;
};

struct Bar : public Base {
    virtual void funct_a() {
        printf("I am Bar:: funct A\n");
    }

    virtual void funct_base() {
        Base::funct_base(); 
    }
};
```

EDIT:

The question is, there is one base class, and two different derived classes that inherit from the same base class.  Is there a way to access a base class method through derived class interface without adding a base class method wrapper?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: @RSahu Thank you for feedback, I added an edit, does the edit make it more clear?

Comment: There is one point unclear to me. When you define interface iBar then funct_a is an abstract class. Do you want to provide an implementation for funct_a in IBar or just in Bar? Andwhy Bar isnot derived from IBar?

Comment: @user1135541, it's still not clear. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I could be such an idiot, yes Bar is derived from IBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a abstract base class `IBase` with a [Abstract method](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/71019/) `funct_base` and make the interface class a [Virtual base classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) of the classes `Base`, `IFoo` and `IBar`:

```
struct IBase {
    virtual void funct_base() = 0;
};

struct Base : public virtual IBase {
    virtual void funct_base() override {    printf("Common function for class Foo and class Bar\n"); }
};

struct IFoo : public virtual IBase {
    virtual void funct_a() = 0;
};

struct Foo : public IFoo, public Base {
    virtual void funct_a() override { printf("I am Foo:: funct A\n"); }
};

class IBar : public virtual IBase {
    virtual void funct_a() = 0;
};

class Bar : public IBar, public Base {
    virtual void funct_a() override { printf("I am Bar:: funct A\n"); }
};
```

Comment: Works perfect, it compiles and does access the `funct_base()`, this saves a ton of lines of wrapper code to maintain...